# Proof that the mean is a complete sufficient statistic and the sample variance is an ancillary statistic

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, complete-statistics, ancillary-statistics

I have $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n $ that are random samples from the single variate $N(\mu,\sigma^2) $. I want to prove that the mean $\bar{X}$ and the sample variance  $s_x ^2 = \frac{1}{(n- 1)} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 $  are independent.

As I understand it, I can use Basu's Theorem. Since $\bar{X}$ is a complete sufficient statistic, and $s_x^2$ is an ancillary statistic, Basu's theorem states that they are indeed independent.

I understand why $\bar{X}$ is a complete sufficient statistic logically, but I can't figure out how to show it mathematically. Same goes with the sample variance. Could someone please explain (mathematically) why $\bar{X}$ is a complete sufficient statistic, and $s_x^2$ is an ancillary statistic? In most sources I've checked this fact just seems obvious and they don't show the proof...

Comment: Complete sufficiency of sample mean follows from the fact that the pdf of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a member of exponential family. And sample variance is ancillary because its distribution does not depend on the parameter $\mu$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47350/proof-of-the-independence-of-the-sample-mean-and-sample-variance.